# Add ajax calls to a folder in Zend

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

Is there a way to create an Ajax folder inside application, so that I can then add each controllers ajax as a seperate controller in that ajax folder?

For instance, say I have IndexController, EmployeeController, MemberController. Inside Ajax folder, I want to have the same three names as well.

Then If I want to call an ajax action, I could refer to /ajax/member/whatever.

Is this possible with zend?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up [routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html) to create urls like that, but I wouldn't duplicate the controllers as you're suggesting. One controller can handle both html and ajax requests. You could include a format parameter in your url like this: /member/21/format/ajax

Then the member viewAction can check the format variable. If it's ajax, you can disable your layout and return the ajax response.